pymssql cannot connect to an ssh forwarded SQL Server
I need to access a SQL Server that is in a network that I do not directly have access to. However, I have SSH access to a host that does have access to this SQL Server. In other cases, I have used an SSH LocalForward to forward the SQL Server's port locally on 127.0.2.3:11433 and this has worked fine.
In this particular instance, however, it does not, and it always throws an OperationalError when doing
pymssql.connect("127.0.2.3:11433", "user", "password")


pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:
Adaptive Server connection failed (127.0.2.3)
DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:
Adaptive Server connection failed (127.0.2.3)

However, if I use the node-based mssql commandline utility, I can connect to the SSH-forwarded server.
When I go onto the server that I have SSH access to and I do the same thing from there (adjusting the port and IP address of course), I do get access.
So in short, the problem occurs with:

one particular SQL Server
when using pymssql only
when it is forwarded over ssh

Might it be a bug in pymssql? Filed here: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/888

The officially supported library is pyodbc, not pymssql. As the docs say: Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver. pyodbc works with Microsoft's own ODBC driver that's actively supported and maintained on Windows, Linux, Mac, with frequent releases. Have you tried working with pyodbc?

First please update to the latest pymssql version - 2.3.0.
Then, try different tds_version like here #860.
If it still fails, then set environment variable TDSDUMP/TDSCONFIIG and try to analyze the logs. See FreeTDS logging

Thanks! Adding tds_version="7.0" indeed worked. So does setting the TDS_VER environment variable. It would be nice if I could include it in the connection string for sqlalchemy, but this does not seem to be supported by pymssql.
